# chrome extension send messages to background in popup has been canceled

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I send a message to the background from the popup panel and immediately close the panel, I find that the message is not actually sent. However, this situation is sporadic. I have tried installing the same version of Chrome on two different computers, and this issue only occurs on the other computer.
this is the code:

```
// popup.js
function sendMessage() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      action: "OPEN_FILE"
  });
  window.close();
}
```

I would like to have a way to listen for when the popup has successfully sent a message and then close the panel.

Comment: All `chrome` methods that return a Promise or have a callback are asynchronous. Call close() inside the callback or after `await`.